# How can server application check if a client application is online?

Tags: c#, winforms, networking, client, server

I have a server application which monitors the clients' activities in the network (all codes are in C# winforms). The server application already has IP addresses of client computers. I want to know how to check

i) if the clients are online (i.e, have opened and been using the client applications) or offline (not using the applications)?

ii) if the clients' computers are opened?

I'm not good in networking and have not got it after searching for hours on internet. Please help!

Edited: I have seen the mentions of HTTP, TCP, UDP, etc. in various sites about server-client applications. What are the differences between them and which one should be used for the above?

PS: Sorry for extra questions. The questions are related so I dont want to make a new post.

Answer (score 3):

You could check if the client machines are online by pinging each machines using their respective IP address.

```
Ping ping = new Ping();
PingReply pingReply = ping.Send("IP Address");

if(pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
{
   //Machine is online
}
```

---

> To check if client machines are using any particular application(if
>   those application are built by you and have access to source code).
>   you can use [WCF inter process communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26841753/how-to-send-strings-to-a-winforms-application-from-another-application-using-met/26842377#26842377). basically you will create
>   a WCF service method and host in a managed environment. to be specific
>   you could host this service in your server win form application. As
>   long as your win form application is running in the server client
>   application installed in individual machines can call this method to
>   send a status(including individual IP address of machines). so server
>   app would know who is running/opened the specific client application
>   in each machine.
>
> If you want to check the status of any other client applications, say
>   you want to get the status to server whenever a client machine runs a
>   "xyz" application. then you need a create a application which runs on
>   individual client machines(Windows service would be best option). job
>   of this application would be to check the running processes
>   periodically to see if any specific application process is running. if
>   then it will invoke the WCF hosted in your server app to send the
>   status.

Comment: Note: in bigger companys icmp echos are often blocked by a firewall

Answer (score 1):

Several options are available, following is a conceptual answer

Your server can maintain available clients in some list. Here you can include Time to live for a specific client (Like session expiring). You client need to send periodical flags to server to indicate that Client is still using the service and when Server get this reply it  can update it list's session so it won't be expire.

Note - The list can be a small data structure which include clients IP and Last flag recieved time. Your server then can go through this list and check for expiration of a client (lets say when time stamp is older than 2 minutes Server assumes client doesn't use the service/not online)

Also other option is your server can send client a flag and get reply back periodically.

Simple Client Server -

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12286/Simple-Client-server-Interactions-using-C [Simple guide]
http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-multi-threaded-server-socket.htm [Multi threaded]

Comment: Can you please explain how to send a flag from server to client and from client to server? A code snippet is appreciated.

Comment: See my edits,

You can use FLAG to indicate many things. ex- Flag can be used to indicate client exits from application. See attached guide to start programming client- server programs :)

Comment: Also you will definitely need Threads :) go through attached tutorials.. they contain Codes

Comment: In multi-threaded server socket program [here](http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-multi-threaded-server-socket.htm) that was given by you (@KCdod), it creates Console application which I dont want to create. Please tell me how to modify the given code to work in winform application.

Comment: Tutorial contained following link - http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-multi-threaded-client-socket.htm

Also it contained link - http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-chat-server-programming.htm  Which is a chat program with winform

:) mark corect answer if I helped

Comment: The answer you have given is helping, but I have not solved the problem yet. I will mark it if the problem is solved, dont worry about it :).